# Which one adds to our body fat - carb or fatty foods?

Tags: body-fat

I've learned that eating carb makes body release Insulin which in turn converts into body fat.

I'm confused whether eating fat adds to our body fat or eating high carb foods like bread, rice, sugar etc.

Answer (score 4):

To basically complete was someone else is saying, its not just a matter of macro-nutrients (carbs, proteins, fats) as not all of these when broken down into their components have equal effects on the body and simply adjusting their ratios is not good enough either.

If you were to say its just a matter of calories in vs. calories out I'd LOVE for someone to accurately measure how much energy one is expending and PROVE that calories in is equal to calories absorbed. The content of what you eat can produce multiple hormonal signals and kick off other chemical balancing processes in the body. (like another was saying about blood glucose).

Carbohydrates are an easy target for fat reduction, because in today's world many people consume WAY, WAY too much of them and typically from poor sources (soda, sugar products). Often simply eliminating soda from a diet is enough to normalize some people.

On top of this the food industry has provided us easy access to many high carb foods made from wheat, barley, and rye which contain gluten and lectin which are a defense a plant uses to try and poison the animal consuming it. Some people have a severe allergy to them (celiacs) and some people barely tolerate it (slow weight gain over time), and others seem to be able to handle it.

In summary: Eating saturated fat found in animal fat and oils, does not make you fat. Eating too much food from shitty sources makes you fat. Try and get your carbohydrates from good sources not containing gluten and lectin. Examples of these would be almost any vegetable, and some tubers like potatoes, sweet potatoes, and white rice (brown rice still has the germ on it containing either gluten or lectin, cannot remember). If you have a lot of weight to lose it can be somewhat beneficial to go easy on carbs for a while, but removing them completely can be hard on your body (but your body CAN make them from fats and proteins).

EDIT: The most DIRECT answer to your question is that BOTH carbs and fatty foods can contribute to weight gain. Conditions at the time in which they are consumed and the composition of them will vary.

Comment: oh, and there are some BAD fats... industrial oils like canola and vegetable oil are chock full of them, and will ruin the quality of the food you're using it to cook.

Comment: Do you have references against which you'd like to prop your argument against gluten?

Comment: How many do you want? 50 or 100? Here's one: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16423158

Comment: How about this one? http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FBJN%2FBJN83_03%2FS0007114500000271a.pdf&code=52df2d45fda41221b810d4d41529542f

Comment: One link does not work while other clearly states this conclusion: "Large-scale epidemiological studies and clinical trials are needed to confirm the association between gluten and schizophrenia, and address the underlying mechanisms by which this association occurs." Is this a reference?

Comment: Okay, start here: http://www.archevore.com/panu-weblog/2009/6/23/the-argument-against-cereal-grains.html there are plenty of sources at the bottom, and this is a well known and respected author. For me there is enough evidence to support this approach.

Comment: See the edit it at the end of my answer... that's about all I have to say on this I think. If you want anything more you can do that research yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Any excess calories will add to body fat.

The most straightforward path is what you described: Blood glucose levels are largely determined by carb intake, and high blood glucose does make the body release insulin, which signals for the body to take up glucose into its glycogen stores, and lipids into fat storage.

Proteins will also get converted into glucose if they are not used for protein stuff (muscle maintenance, etc.) or if your body just really needs extra energy (although in this case, you're probably going to use it, rather than store it). The excess will be stored as fat.

Dietary fat is a slightly different story. It's usually broken down into fatty acids and used for energy in that form (and it's a lot of energy compared to what carbs or proteins provide). That means less of your glucose is needed (and you'll have a bunch in your system, assuming you're not just eating 100% dietary fat), and the excess will be stored as fat.

Comment: Does it include proteins too?

Comment: Yes, although your body will first use proteins for protein stuff (muscle maintenance, etc.) before converting it to glucose and then fat if that glucose is more than needed.

Comment: Care to explain why his idea was wrong?

Comment: His idea isn't wrong, it's just not the complete story. Blood glucose levels are largely determined by carb intake, and high blood glucose does make the body release insulin, which signals for the body to take up glucose into its glycogen stores, and lipids into fat storage. But, both proteins and fats can also be converted to glucose.

Comment: However, fats are normally broken down into fatty acids and used for energy in that form (and it's quite a bit of energy compared to carbs or proteins) but that means less of your glucose is needed, and the excess will be stored as fat.

Comment: @friz It would be great if you took your three comments here and wrote them up into your own answer. I'd upvote.